# Problems rotating BufferedImage

Tags: java, image, rotation, affinetransform

I have some problems with rotating images in Java using the AffineTransform class.

I have the following method for creating a rotated (90 degrees) copy of an image:

```
private BufferedImage createRotatedCopy(BufferedImage img, Rotation rotation) {
    int w = img.getWidth();
    int h = img.getHeight();

    BufferedImage rot = new BufferedImage(h, w, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    double theta;
    switch (rotation) {
        case CLOCKWISE:
            theta = Math.PI / 2;
            break;
        case COUNTERCLOCKWISE:
            theta = -Math.PI / 2;
            break;
        default:
            throw new AssertionError();
    }

    AffineTransform xform = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(theta, w / 2, h / 2);
    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) rot.createGraphics();
    g.drawImage(img, xform, null);
    g.dispose();

    return rot;
}
```

Rotation is a simple enum with the values NONE, CLOCKWISE and COUNTERCLOCKWISE.

The symptoms of my problems are displayed here:

http://perp.se/so/rotate_problems.html

So, the rotation works OK, but the resulting images aren't anchored to the correct coordinates (or how one should put it). And since I don't really know what the heck I'm doing in the first place (my linear algebra is weak), I don't know how to solve this on my own.

I've tried with some random fiddling with the AffineTransform instance, but it hasn't helped me (of course). I've tried googling (and searching SO), but all examples I've seen basically use the same approach as I do... which doesn't work for me.

Thankful for advice.

Comment: Equivalent question for .NET: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225363/c-rotate-bitmap-90-degrees

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you must express the transform as a single rotation, the anchor point depends on the direction of rotation: Either `(w/2, w/2)` or `(h/2, h/2)`.

But it's probably simpler to express as `translate; rotate; translate`, e.g.

```
AffineTransform xform = new AffineTransform();
xform.translate(0.5*h, 0.5*w);
xform.rotate(theta);
xform.translate(-0.5*w, -0.5*h);
```

Also consider using `getQuadrantRotateInstance` instead of `getRotateInstance`.

Comment: I get what you're saying, and I have tried that too. The problem persists, however. They're still being drawn "outside" the target area, albeit on the "other side" horizontally, so to speak. I could supply some more screenshots if it's unclear what I'm getting at.

Comment: @perp, you're right, fixed.  I've tested the new version and it works.

Comment: Works like a charm! I think I have a better understanding of what's going on now, too. Thanks!

Comment: In case that can help anyone: after applying this solution, my image was still partially cropped but only on one axis. The problem was not on the transform, but due to the fact that I was using a wrong image type. So think about that too :)

Answer (score 3):

Since you only need 90 degree rotation you can avoid using the AffineTransform stuff:

```
public BufferedImage rotate90DX(BufferedImage bi) {
    int width = bi.getWidth();
    int height = bi.getHeight();
    BufferedImage biFlip = new BufferedImage(height, width, bi.getType());
    for(int i=0; i<width; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<height; j++)
            biFlip.setRGB(height-1-j, width-1-i, bi.getRGB(i, j));
    return biFlip;
}
```

This also avoids cutting off edges of rectangular images.

From: http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/2936

Comment: Just a heads up, forcing a direct access to the RGB pixel values takes the image out of the accelerated pipeline in Java2D. This approach may give you the result you want, but it is much slower.

Comment: I tested this code and it not simply rotates the image, it also changes left and right (like in a mirror)

Answer (score 1):

You could try an alternative appoach and create an Icon from the image and then use a [Rotated Icon](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/rotated-icon/).

Or you can try this old code I found in the Sun forums:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class RotateImage {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL("https://blogs.oracle.com/jag/resource/JagHeadshot-small.jpg");
        BufferedImage original = ImageIO.read(url);
        GraphicsConfiguration gc = getDefaultConfiguration();
        BufferedImage rotated1 = tilt(original, -Math.PI/2, gc);
        BufferedImage rotated2 = tilt(original, +Math.PI/4, gc);
        BufferedImage rotated3 = tilt(original, Math.PI, gc);
        display(original, rotated1, rotated2, rotated3);
    }

    public static BufferedImage tilt(BufferedImage image, double angle, GraphicsConfiguration gc) {
        double sin = Math.abs(Math.sin(angle)), cos = Math.abs(Math.cos(angle));
        int w = image.getWidth(), h = image.getHeight();
        int neww = (int)Math.floor(w*cos+h*sin), newh = (int)Math.floor(h*cos+w*sin);
        int transparency = image.getColorModel().getTransparency();
        BufferedImage result = gc.createCompatibleImage(neww, newh, transparency);
        Graphics2D g = result.createGraphics();
        g.translate((neww-w)/2, (newh-h)/2);
        g.rotate(angle, w/2, h/2);
        g.drawRenderedImage(image, null);
        return result;
    }

    public static GraphicsConfiguration getDefaultConfiguration() {
        GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        GraphicsDevice gd = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
        return gd.getDefaultConfiguration();
    }

    public static void display(BufferedImage im1, BufferedImage im2, BufferedImage im3, BufferedImage im4) {
        JPanel cp = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,2));
        addImage(cp, im1, "original");
        addImage(cp, im2, "rotate -PI/2");
        addImage(cp, im3, "rotate +PI/4");
        addImage(cp, im4, "rotate PI");

        JFrame f = new JFrame("RotateImage");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setContentPane(cp);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    static void addImage(Container cp, BufferedImage im, String title) {
        JLabel lbl = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(im));
        lbl.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(title));
        cp.add(lbl);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this might be your issue.

```
AffineTransform xform = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(theta, w / 2, h / 2);
```

Why not try?

```
AffineTransform xform = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(theta);
```

OR

```
g.transform(AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(theta));
g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, w/2, h/2, null, null);
```