# saving pictures in portrait orientation

Tags: android, gridview, camera, landscape-portrait

I am working on app that use camera preview to take pictures and displaying them in grid view in other activity. But when I take a portrait picture it is saved in my galaxy S4 SD Card in landscape and also display it in grid view in landscape!

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRwPx.jpg)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzPmh.jpg)

Gridview Activity:

```
public class GridViewActivity extends Activity {

private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.grid_view);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
    gridview.setAdapter(imageAdapter);

    String ExternalStorageDirectoryPath = Environment
            .getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath();

    String targetPath = ExternalStorageDirectoryPath + "/JCG Camera";

    File targetDirector = new File(targetPath);

    File[] files = targetDirector.listFiles();
    for (File file : files){

        imageAdapter.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
    } 
}
```

in ImageAdapter:

```
void add(String path){
    this.path = path;
    imageList.add(path); 
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {  
        imageView = new ImageView(context);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(320, 320));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    Bitmap bm = decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(imageList.get(position), 320, 320);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
    return imageView;
}

public Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(String path, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    Bitmap bm = null;
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options); 

    return bm;   
}

public int calculateInSampleSize(

    BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
        if (width > height) {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float)height / (float)reqHeight);    
        } else {
            inSampleSize = Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth);    
        }   
    }

    return inSampleSize;    
}
```

in camera activity:

```
private PictureCallback getPictureCallback() {
    PictureCallback picture = new PictureCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

            //make a new picture file

            File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();

            if (pictureFile == null) {
                return;
            }
            try {

                //write the file

                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(myContext, "Picture saved: " + pictureFile.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }

            //refresh camera to continue preview

            mPreview.refreshCamera(mCamera);
        }
    };
    return picture;
}

private static File getOutputMediaFile() {

    //make a new file directory inside the "sdcard" folder

    File mediaStorageDir = new File("/sdcard/", "JCG Camera");

    //if this "JCGCamera folder does not exist

    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {

        //if you cannot make this folder return

        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            return null;
        }
    }


    //take the current timeStamp

    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;

    //and make a media file:

    mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
    return mediaFile;
}
```

I read about EXIF and exifinerface, but I do not know how to use it in my code!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rotate and flip bitmap in onPictureTaken](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16228654/how-to-rotate-and-flip-bitmap-in-onpicturetaken)

Answer (score 0):

ExiftInterface is a good approach I think. They only thing is that you must have a mechanism that tells you which way your image needs to be rotated (eg. clockwise, counterclockwise). This is what I am using to rotate image.

```
try {
    //You must replace _filePaths.get(position) with the desired object
    //You are trying to extract the rotation info. In your case is your data 
    //But I think you have to save your image first, before you can rotate it.
    ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(_filePaths.get(position));

    //Here you extract the image's rotation info.
    int rotation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL );

    //Here you can convert it to degrees. Using helper method.
    int roationInDegrees = exifToDegress(rotation);
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

    //This is where you check if the rotation of the image is not what you want. 0f indicates a portait Image.
    if(rotation != 0f){

    //Here you specify which way you want to rotate your bitmap according 
    //To the result of helper method.
    matrix.preRotate(roationInDegrees);
    image = Bitmap.createBitmap(image,0, 0, imageWidth, imageWidth, matrix, true);
}
} catch (IOException e1) {
     e1.printStackTrace();
    Log.d("activity#fail", e1.getMessage());
}

private int exifToDegress(int exifOrientation) {
    if (exifOrientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) { return 90; } 
    else if (exifOrientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180) {  return 180; } 
    else if (exifOrientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) {  return 270; }            
    return 0; 
}
```

Make sure you put code inside Try and catch in case the image your are attempting to rotate does not contain any "Orientation" information. Try adding this code right before you write the "data" with your fileoutputstream object.

Good Luck.