# How to Rotate Image 90 degrees

Tags: bitmap, vala

Is there vala class that can rotate a bitmap?
The way to accomplish this using C# is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2225381/398460) (very slick) but the same code

```
public void RotateAndSaveImage(String input, String output)
{
    using (Image img = Image.FromFile(input))
    {
        img.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
        img.Save(output, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
}
```

in vala causes

```
test.vala:48.22-48.24: error: syntax error, expected `)'
        using (Image img = Image.FromFile(input))
                     ^^^
```

I looked through the [Valadoc](https://live.gnome.org/Valadoc) but could not find an image class and vala [Bitmap](http://references.valadoc.org/#!api=cogl-1.0/Cogl.Bitmap) didn't seem very useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd want to use a [Gdk.Pixbuf](http://references.valadoc.org/#!api=gdk-pixbuf-2.0/Gdk.Pixbuf), which uses the GDK+ libraries to manipulate images.

```
var img = Gdk.Pixbuf.from_file(input);
var rotate_image = img.rotate_simple(90);
rotate_image.save(output, "jpeg");
```

It's worth noting that Vala is not meant to be directly compatible with C#.