# half image haft blank white with horizontal partition in between in C# code

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, image, white-box

How can I create this image when I get a simple rectangular image using C# code.

[image: this is what the image looks like]

```
private Bitmap MergeImages(Image image1, Image image2)  
{  
  Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(image1.Width + image2.Width, Math.Max(image1.Height, image2.Height));  
  using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))  
  {  
    g.DrawImage(image1, 0, 0);  
    g.DrawImage(image2, image1.Width, 0);  
  }  
    
  return bitmap;  
}
```

Comment: Draw a simple triangular image over it?

Comment: Or rotate it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225363/c-sharp-rotate-bitmap-90-degrees