# Upload image file size is more than actual file size

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, image-processing, fileapi

I am uploading an image in c# using a fileapi plugin. My actual file size is 60kb but after uploading the file size appears as 350kb on the server. Why is this happening? Here is my code for saving an image:

```
    public JsonResult SaveImageFile(byte[] file)
    {
        var filesData = Request.Files[0];
        string fileName = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssffff");
        if (filesData != null && filesData.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            string directoryPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/Products/"), itemId);
            string filePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/Products/"), itemId, fileName+".jpeg");
            if (!Directory.Exists(directoryPath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryPath);
            }               

            Image img = Image.FromStream(filesData.InputStream, true, true);

            img =  img.GetThumbnailImage(800, 600, () => false, IntPtr.Zero);
            img.Save(Path.ChangeExtension(filePath, "jpeg"));
            Image thumb = img.GetThumbnailImage(411, 274, () => false, IntPtr.Zero);
            thumb.Save(Path.ChangeExtension(filePath, "png"));
            ViewBag.MimeType = "image/pjpeg";
            TempData["ItemFilePath"] = "~/Images/Products/" + itemId +"/"+ fileName+".jpeg";
            TempData["ItemThumbnailFilePath"] = "~/Images/Products/" + itemId + "/" + fileName + ".png";
            TempData["ItemFileName"] = fileName + ".jpeg";
        }
        return Json(new
        {
            Success = true,
            Title = "Success",
            FileName = relativePath
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

Can anyone tell me what is the problem with my code? I am designing shopping cart in which image size must be small. The thumbnail image (`png`) also taking more size 200kb

Comment: Well you're not saving the original stream - you're converting it using `GetThumbnailImage`. To get the original data size, just save the original stream - check that that works. Then if you want to look into resizing etc, you can entirely separate that aspect from the upload aspect.

Comment: i already tried.also same issue with orignal stream.

Comment: Please confirm that you're actually asking how to apply image compression... If so, it's a dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484759/quality-of-a-saved-jpg-in-c-sharp

Comment: Please show the code that uses the original stream. I'd be astonished to see that really giving a problem.

Comment: As an aside, I'd *strongly* recommend against using `DateTime.Now` for this - use `DateTime.UtcNow` to avoid confusion due to time zones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final size is most likely increasing because you're not passing your image format on `img.Save()` method.

You should change

```
img.Save(Path.ChangeExtension(filePath, "jpeg"));
```

to

```
img.Save(Path.ChangeExtension(filePath, "jpeg"), ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Same for the png image (`ImageFormat.Png)`